# I use liulishuo.filedownloader.File downloaded but not write phone storage where am i making a mistake?

Tags: android, file, download

i use `liulishuo.filedownloader` library in the android application. In completed method toast showing on-screen when the activity starts but not writing in phone or emulator storage. My MainActivity code and Manifest permission code is below where am i making a mistake?

```java
//MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FileDownloader.init(getApplicationContext());
        FileDownloader.getImpl().create("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg")
                .setPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString())
                .setListener(new FileDownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    protected void pending(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void started(BaseDownloadTask task) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void connected(BaseDownloadTask task, String etag, boolean isContinue, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void progress(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void blockComplete(BaseDownloadTask task) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void retry(final BaseDownloadTask task, final Throwable ex, final int retryingTimes, final int soFarBytes) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void completed(BaseDownloadTask task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void paused(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void error(BaseDownloadTask task, Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void warn(BaseDownloadTask task) {
                    }
                }).start();
    }

}
```

```java
//Manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: if you are using Android 6.0 devices you have to use runtime permission

Comment: I use Android 10.0 emulator

Comment: so you have to..